# execute a script that outputs a result in a txt file or ini using the cmd line in php

Tags: php, command-line, export, output

i want to run a simple line in my commandline in windows to run a script that reads ip addresses and i want it to out output in a text file.

This is the script

```
<?php
     $lines = file('ipaddresses.ini', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES); 
     foreach($lines as $line){
         echo $line;  

         $host   = $line;
         echo("Ping Output:");
         system("ping -n 4 $host",$result);

         if ($result == 0)
             echo "Ping successful!";
         else
             echo "Ping unsuccessful!";

     } 
 ?>
```

And this is the command line

```
C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.13>php.exe -f "C:\wamp\www\hello.php"
```

Comment: Er... what's with all the `<br>` tags then? This is some sort of insane pseudo-PHP/HTML/nonsense, I love it!

Comment: @deed02392 rab edited it in the wrong way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Saving the output to a file can be done through the command line. Append `> [name of file]` to the command and it will then store all of the output from the script into the specified file name.

```
C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.13>php.exe -f "C:\wamp\www\hello.php" > C:\output.txt
```

Comment: when I run the cmd line and give the file to save into. it gives me this error:

Warning: file(ipaddresses.ini): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\wamp\www\hello.php on line 2

Call 

Stack:
    0.0005     326792   1. {main}() C:\wamp\www\hello.php:0
    0.0005     326912   2. file() C:\wamp\www

\hello.php:2


Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\wamp\www\hello.php on line 3

Call Stack:
    0.0005    

 326792   1. {main}() C:\wamp\www\hello.php:0

Answer (score 0):

Save this into `C:\wamp\www\hello.php`, then execute it like:

```
>php.exe -f "C:\wamp\www\hello.php" > C:\wamp\www\output.txt
```

with a Windows command prompt. Make sure there's a file called ipaddresses.ini that consists of only new-line delimited, valid IP address.

```
<?php
$lines = file('ipaddresses.ini', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
foreach($lines as $line)
{ 
    echo $line . "\n";
    $ip = $line;
    exec("ping -n 3 $ip", $outcome, $status);

    if ($status == 0)
    {
        echo "Ping successful!\n";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Ping unsuccessful!\n";
    }
}
?>​
```

Comment: Error still appears i removed all other ip addresses and add just one, to error says no file or directory in \confirm.php which means does seem right

Comment: My fopen and foreach statments seem not want to funtion when i use the cmdline

Comment: Where is confirm.php from? Where is your ipaddresses.ini file stored?

Comment: confirm.php is stored in c:\wamp\www\ping\ and the ipaddresses.ini is stored in the same location. I does seem that fopen does like when I use the cmdline to call the script

Comment: fopen doesn't care who called it. Don't forget if you're using paths in Windows with PHP escape the backslashes or use forward slashes. `C:\\foo\\bar` or `C:/foo/bar`

Comment: thanks it worked i wonder how it will work on a server if a user on client machine wants to access the script.